# Is it possible to create a custom mongodb cursor in meteor?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a Student collection and a Person Collection.
Person contains the fields: name, address, etc
Student contains: rollno, and a person field that stores the person._id for this student

Now I want to show the name of student in the student template, but note that there's no `name` field in Student, I'll need to get that from that student's Person document.

Is there a way to get a mongodb cursor on the client that has the student information as well as selective field from that student's person document?

Also, is there a better or more standard way of achieving what I'm trying to achieve?

Note: I don't want to use redundancy and store the `name` field on the Student document, so that's not a solution

Comment: Why do you have two separate collections?

Comment: It's a bit like inheritance, a Person can be a Student, Teacher, or both. So the Student/Teacher specific fields are in their respective collections, while the generic every-man details like name, address, contact details are in the Person collection. 
Does that make sense somewhat?

Comment: Yes, but not for schema design. Why not have student documents have additional fields that non-students don't have?  Why have a separate collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the accepted answer in this thread:

[Possible bug when observing a cursor, when deleting from collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10643509/possible-bug-when-observing-a-cursor-when-deleting-from-collection)

It involves using a modified version of the built-in `_publishCursor` titled `publishModifiedCursor`, which allows you to specify a callback to add properties to each document in the cursor you are publishing.

Answer (score 2):

> is there a better or more standard way of achieving what I'm trying to
>   achieve?

It sounds like you are trying to read all information about a student in one read - the only way to do that is to have all that information in a single document.

Flexible schema of document databases allow you to have documents in a single collection which are not required to have the same schema, aka number of fields.

So I would recommend that you consider why you actually need separate collections for person and student - this causes writes to two collections when you add a student (and while a single write is atomic, two writes are not) and it also causes the issue you have now where you need to have two separate reads to get all information about a student.

This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10521901/mongodb-schema-design-for-polymorphic-objects) is somewhat related to your situation.

Answer (score 0):

I would change your code to have a role / job attribute in the Person object.
It's semantic, at least for me, and think about the difficulty level in someone changing jobs in your original method vs simply changing the role.

Then you could just search

```
Persons.find {role: 'student'}
```

And that would just be totally analogous with having a student object.

As Asya said, the students can just have extra fields the other ones done have.